# asp.net - prevent downloading a specific file

Tags: asp.net, security

I have a website where I also have a "UserFiles" directory which is protected to view its content in browser:

> This Virtual Directory does not allow contents to be listed.

The problem is that I have some files here which, if you know the name of the file, for instance:

http://example.com/UserFiles/file.ppt

you can download it.

**Is there any way to protect this also from web.config? Or, if the user tries to access this, to do a redirect to the login page?**

Please note that I do not use Forms authentication but a custom login and Windows authentication is On.

Thanks,

**UPDATE**: I will try this for the moment: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=270

Answer (score 2):

If you still want to do this via `web.config`, your `web.config` file should have this under the `httpHandlers` section:

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="*" path="*.ppt" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" />
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

That will block all .ppt files.

Comment: I wonder if this would work if a directory is specified as the path?

Answer (score 0):

When someone needs to download one of those files, do you just redirect them to a URL similar to the one you gave there?

The alternative would be to have a page defined that returns the file, which you can then put whatever permission checks you want in.  Using this method also allows you to move that User folder entirely outside of the web folder, so those URLs aren't available at all.

eg:

```
C:\UserFiles\
C:\inetpub\MyWebFolder\
```

You just have to make sure that the user account that the web application is running under has appropriate permissions on the C:\UserFiles\ folder.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, moving the folder would imply a lot of refactoring in the code so I try to find an alternative... And yes, I'm giving plain urls to the logged in users...

Comment: In that case the IHttpHandler option you are trying is the only other option I can think of.